# Fastest way to move higher or lower 64 bits in integer SSE register

Tags: sse, simd, cpu-registers

What's the fastest way to move only the higher or lower 64 bits from an integer SSE register to another? With SSE 4.1, it can be done with a single `pblendw` instruction (`_mm_blend_epi16`). But what about older SSE versions? Shift and unpack? AND and OR? `movsd` despite of the bypass delay?

Closely related question: [Best way to shuffle 64-bit portions of two __m128i's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293695/best-way-to-shuffle-64-bit-portions-of-two-m128is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move the low 64 bits from src to dst, preserving the high 64 bits of dst:

```
movsd dst, src
```

To move the high 64 bits from src to dst, preserving the low 64 bits of dst:

```
shufps dst, src, E4h
```

Bypass delays generally only add latency, not dispatch or execute or retirement resources, so they are usually only a concern when comparing otherwise equivalent sequences (i.e. if there were a single-instruction equivalent that stayed in the integer domain, you'd prefer to use it for integer arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks. In my case `movsd` initially turned out to be just as fast as `psrldq/punpcklqdq` or `pshufd/punpcklqdq`, but it reduced code size and allowed to reorder instructions for a small performance gain. It seems that I was overly concerned about bypass delays.

Comment: Is there anyway to move the low `src` to high `dest` while preserving low `src`? I'm catching an unaligned load finding from UBsan, so I need to find something other than `_mm_loaddup_pd`.

Comment: @jww: It's in Peter Cordes' answer below: `movlhps`.

Answer (score 5):

Agner Fog's [Optimizing Assembly](http://agner.org/optimize/) guide has a nice set of tables of instructions for various kinds of data movement.  (section 13.3).

For combining data from two regs into one, your options include:

```
MOVLHPS   # SSE. Low qword unchanged, high qword from low of source
MOVHLPS   # SSE. Low qword from high of source, high qword unchanged
MOVSD     # SSE2. Low qword from source (register only), high qword unchanged
# memory-source-only insns:
 MOVLPS/D  # SSE1/2.  Low qword from memory, high qword unchanged
 MOVHPS/D  # SSE1/2. High qword from memory, low qword unchanged
SHUFPD    # SSE2. Low qword from any position of destination. high qword from any position of source
PUNPCKLQDQ # SSE2. Low qword unchanged, high qword from low of source
PUNPCKHQDQ # SSE2. Low qword from high of destination, high qword from high of source
MOVQ       # SSE2. Low qword from source, high qword set to zero
PBLENDW    # SSE4.1
PINSRQ     # SSE4.1 (only takes the low64 of src)
```

Descriptions copy/pasted from Agner Fog's table, for which he has the copyright.

So `shufpd` looks like your best bet for inserting the high64 from another reg.  Other options would require it to be in the low64 of the src (for `punpcklqdq` or `movlhps`).

Comment: Regarding `MOVSD`, then [Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=movsd) says unaligned memory is fine. Both `_mm_load_sd` and `_mm_store_sd` state *"`mem_addr` does not need to be aligned on any particular boundary"*. I guess the compiler is doing some extra work for intrinsic users.

Comment: @jww: [`movsd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html) with a memory source zero-extends into an XMM register (and yes, an unaligned address is fine because the width is less than 16 bytes).  `movsd` with a register source merges the low half into the destination.  If you want to merge a low half from memory, use [`movlps`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/MOVLPS.html), that's what it's for (and it *only* works with a memory source, not a register source.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about the fastest, maybe the easiest,

```
_mm_unpacklo_epi64(_mm_setzero_si128(), x)
```

[0, x0]

```
_mm_unpackhi_epi64(_mm_setzero_si128(), x)
```

[0, x1]

```
_mm_move_epi64(x)
```

[x0, 0]

```
_mm_unpackhi_epi64(x, _mm_setzero_si128())
```

[x1, 0]

Comment: I want to preserve the remaining bits of the target register. Sorry for not making that clear.